# UIButton image animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton

Hi,

i'm trying to animate the image of a UIButton between two different image.

Let's say i have two square images, on RED, on BLACK.

When i touch my Button, i want the image of the uibutton to loop from both images, in a smooth animation.

the loop animation must start whenever the user touch down the button and canceled when he touch Up inside or drag exit.

Here is what i do now :

```
-(void)startAnimation:(UIButton *)obj {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{
        [obj setAlpha:0];
        [obj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [obj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated_on"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [obj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated_on"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [obj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated_on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [obj setAlpha:1];
        [obj setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [obj setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [obj setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [obj setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];        

    }];   
}

-(void)stopAnimation:(UIButton *)obj {
   [obj.layer removeAllAnimations]; 
}

- (void)touchDownAnimation:(id)obj {    
    [self startAnimation:obj];
}

- (void)dragEnterAnimation:(id)obj {
    [self startAnimation:obj];
}
- (void)dragExitAnimation:(id)obj {
    [self stopAnimation:obj];
}

- (void)touchUpInsideAnimation:(id)obj {
    [self stopAnimation:obj];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(110, 180, 100, 100);

    UIImageView *animatedButtonBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [animatedButtonBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated_off"]];

    [self.view addSubview:animatedButtonBackground];

    UIButton *animatedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [animatedButton setFrame:frame];

    [animatedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [animatedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnterAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
    [animatedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragExitAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];    
    [animatedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInsideAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:animatedButton];

}
```

it's kinda works, but involving an UIImageView in the process looks like a bad trick to do what i want...

i'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you could use something simpler:

```
button.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                                    nil];
button.imageView.animationDuration = 1;
[button.imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: This method does not work. At least for iOS 6.1. The app crashes on the first line.